# Grant system access to the users according to the days of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server

Database: SQL Server.

I have a scenario where I need to grant system access to the users in according to week days.

I mean that suppose a user A can access the system 7 days of the 
week but the user B can only access the system in Monday, Wednesday and Friday and the user C can access the system only on Sunday, Tuesday, Thursday.

How to design the table for this scenario?

I have designed a table.

**USER**:

```
userId int not null,
userName varchar(25),
userStatus varchar(1)
```

Now how to implement the above scenario? Please suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But here I want the business logic for the weekdays access, not storage of password. I just created a table for the ease. Please focus on the main issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Please reply if you have any solution for the problem. That will be highly appreciated.

Comment: One way is to add 2 more tables to your database:
One that will hold the week days and one that will join the users and weekdays.

Answer (score 1):

I will go with a single table in master database.Table contains username(same name as login) and days they have access

```
create table usersacess
(
username varchar(30),
accessdays char(10)
)


insert into usersacess
select 'testlogin1','sunday'
union all
select 'testlogin','monday'
union all
select 'testlogin','tuesday'
```

Once you have the above info,you need to create a logon trigger,you can choose to log to DB as well..

```
alter TRIGGER connection_limit_trigger
ON ALL SERVER  with execute as 'sa'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
if exists(select 1 from usersacess where username=original_login())
begin
if not exists(select 1 from usersacess where username=ORIGINAL_LOGIN() and accessdays=datename(dw,getdate()))
begin
rollback;
end
end

END;
```

**Few points to note:**

> 1.with Execute as SA is important,since some logins might not have access to read the usersaccess table
>   2.First exists makes sure ,that we are not checking for all users
>   3.Login name in usersacess table should match with original name created for user

Now if you try to test,testlogin1 only can access today,since it is sunday